# What is a better alternative to $("#myDiv").html(myResult); in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently using Ajax to update a feed of information. The Ajax should **add to the current list of results** rather than replace the existing results.

So far I have created the Ajax required to fetch the data from a database, but in the callback function I am using the following callback function

```
fetchPosts.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(fetchPosts.readyState === 4) {
        $("#resultfeed").html(fetchPosts.responseText);
    }
}
```

Obviously using `$("#resultfeed").html(fetchPosts.responseText);` in the callback function means that any prior results are overwritten on the page. How can I change this so that the results add to the current list of results?

Comment: Use .prepend(), .append() functions

Comment: does your feed only provide new results and no duplicates which have already been rendered?

Comment: In addition to the  $("#resultfeed").append(fetchPosts.responseText); or  $("#resultfeed").prepend(fetchPosts.responseText); you might want to use JQuery to make the ajax calls as well e.g. $.get("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
 $("#resultfeed").append(data); 
});

Comment: Why use jquery where it is not already used and is not needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use append or prepend

```
$("#resultfeed").append(fetchPosts.responseText);  // Adds at the end
$("#resultfeed").prepend(fetchPosts.responseText); // Adds at the top
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried both of these, but neither seem to work... In both cases, the fist time the function is executed, the results are displayed. However, if the function is executed again there is no change to the list of results. Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: Admittedly I am currently trying to fetch the same data twice - could this be the issue?

Comment: It should work perfectly. I am giving you this link the basic functionality of append and prepend https://jsbin.com/dalovow/6/edit?html,js,console,output  hope this helps

Comment: Even Though you try to fetch the same data it should work until you clears the html content inside it. Give it a try once.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a fiddle and I'm sure I'll work it out from your answer and example.

Comment: Lovely !! All the best